# Find a word inside text file using Pentaho Kettle/Spoon/PDI

Tags: t-sql, pentaho, etl, kettle, pdi

I am creating a Data Comparison/Verification script using SQL and Spoon PDI. We're moving data between two servers, and to make sure we've got all the data we have SQL queries showing a date then the quantity of rows transferred.

**Example:**
Serv1: 20150522 | 100
Serv2: 20150522 | 100

The script will then try to union these values, and if it fails we'll get a fail email. However, we wish to change this setup to write the outcome to a text file, and based on that text file send either a pass or fail email.

The idea behind this is we have multiple tables we're comparing, so we wish to write all the outcomes of each comparison (eight) to a text file and based off the final text file, send the outcome - rather than spamming our email inbox if multiple steps fail.

The format of the text file we wish to have is either match -> send email or mismatch [step-name] [date] -> send email.

Usually I wouldn't ask a question if I haven't tried anything first, but I've searched everywhere on Google, tried the knowledge I currently have and nothing is going the way I wish it to. I believe this is due to the logic I am using.

I am not asking for a solution to this, or for someone to do it for me. I am simply asking for guidance along the correct path.

Comment: You've said that the logic you're using is causing the problem - could you edit the question to explain what that logic is? Also, is that logic in Pentaho Kettle/Spoon? It's not too clear in your question.

Comment: I need to write eight outcomes of a comparison to a text file. Once all jobs are completed and written their outcome to text file, I then need to search the text file for keyword "mismatch". If Spoon cannot find "mismatch", then a pass email should be sent. If it can find "mismatch", then a fail email should be sent.

Comment: can you provide sample output format of your text file include match or mismatch thing also.

Comment: The output of the text file is currently:

StepName Match
StepName2 Match
StepName3 MisMatch 20150529

I need to search through the text file and find 'MisMatch'. If there is no 'MisMatch' found, send a pass email. If there is a 'MisMatch', then send a fail email.

I've got this working using a C# application that runs through a batch file after the Spoon Job, however I need a solution that uses only Spoon PDI.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in a transformation where there are steps for each union where the result of each step is the *comparison_name* and the *result*. This would result in a data set at the end that looks something like this:

**comparison_name | result**

---

Union A | true

Union B | false

Union C | true

---

You would then be able to output those results to a text file in another step to get your result file to sent out regardless of whether the job passed or failed.

Lastly you would loop through the *result* row in the stream, and if all are true, you could do an email step to send out a "pass" email, and if one is false, send out a "fail" email.

EDIT:

To get the date of the pass or fail you could either get the date from each individual union query result by adding it to the query like so:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE
```

Or you could use the *Get System Info* step in spoon which has multiple ways of injecting the current date into the data stream. (system date fixed, start date range of the transformation, today 00:00:00, etc.)

Comment: This solution would work however I need the date that the data verification failed. I pull data from the last 7 days and compare it day by day with a Quantity. In my comment above you can see a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: I edited the answer to include some solutions to add the date of failure.